# Is it possible to load external scripts in Universal Windows Platform app

Tags: uwp

**Question**: Is it possible to load external JavaScript in a `UWP JavaScript` project? If so, how? I tried the following example and it did not work

I used this [official Microsoft tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/get-started/create-a-hello-world-app-js-uwp) of a simple `UWP JS app`. In order to test whether UWP JS app works with JavaScript files loaded externally, I replaced the `Index.html` file of the project with the following content. But, it seems it did not use the Bootstrap files referenced in the `<head>` tag - as is evident from the display of the index.html file shown below:

**Index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container-fluid">
        <h1>Three equal width columns</h1>
        <p>Note: Try to add a new div with class="col" inside the row class - this will create four equal-width columns.</p>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col" style="background-color:lavender;">.col</div>
            <div class="col" style="background-color:orange;">.col</div>
            <div class="col" style="background-color:lavender;">.col</div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

**Display of the above file when the app is run in VS2017** [NOT showing three columns with equal width.]

[image]

**NOTE**:

This [W3Schools example](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_grid_ex&stacked=h) with same html as in the Index.html file (of UWP app) correctly shows the display of `three columns with equal widths`:

Comment: What have you done with the bootstrap library?

Comment: @BarryWang-MSFT I'm more interested in knowing whether or not we can use external JavaScript in a `UWP app`. And if we can, how? The above post just shows an example where external scripts are not working. To elaborate more, I've just updated my post title and question after reading your comment.

Comment: My colleage seems replied your issue on MSDN, please have a check on it first: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/678f969a-8504-4dc7-a366-4b6dfe926584/uwpjsis-it-possible-to-load-external-scripts-in-universal-windows-platform-app?forum=wpdevelop

Comment: @BarryWang-MSFT Thank you Barry Wang. The link you provided helped.

Comment: Thanks for your confirm. I will ask my college to also post the answer here to make this clear to other communities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**>> Is it possible to load external JavaScript in a UWP JavaScript project? If so, how?**

Well it depends on where you call the scripts. If you call them in local content like you did in JS project. This is not allowed. This is by design for security reason. But if you run the Script in a WebView control, the answer is yes. The Scripts could be loaded.